# Which custom post types in Wordpress should be Noindexed for optimal SEO?

Tags: seo, noindex, nofollow, woocommerce

I'm using the All In One SEO pack, and read several guides on recommended/optimal settings.

However every guide typically shows just Pages, Posts & Media, whereas my site currently has a ton of post types as shown here:

[image]

I'm no SEO whiz but my impression is that as much non-important content should be noindexed as possible to give greater weight to what I want to rank for - pages, posts, and store products. Should everything else be disabled, and if so, should the pattern be repeated for NOFOLLOW/NOODP/NOYDIR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasons to prevent Google from indexing content are:

- The content should be private and not available through search engines
- Nobody would be searching for the information and thus wouldn't be of interest to search users
- The content is in a format that is not meant for human consumption
- The content is thin or low quality  (if it isn't going to satisfy the searcher, such that they leave unhappy, it will ultimately reflect badly on your site as a whole)

I've never seen Google index CSS or JavaScript files, so there shouldn't be a reason to add a noindex to those.   Noindex is typically done with a meta tag in the HTML source code, I'm not sure if your plugin could actually noindex those or not.   If it did, it would have to use a `X-Robots-Tag` header.

It sounds like "orders", "messages", and "refunds" should be private.   You also might not want "coupons" indexed.

"webhooks" shouldn't have human readable content, so you probably want to noindex those.

I'm not sure exactly how you use the other categories, but you could apply my rules above based on your usage.